# Refer to solution from matrix

Tags: assignment

Consider matrix equation

```
m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
l = {{1}, {0}}
p = {{p1}, {p2}}
eq = m.p == l
Solve[eq]
```

Output is

> {{p1 -> -2, p2 -> 3/2}}

But p1 and p2 do not have these values in worksheet :-(

How to refer to each solution as p1 and p2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sol = Solve[eq]
```

[image]

```
Set @@@ sol[[1]];

{p1, p2}
```

[image]

This assignment has the disadvantage that it changes your original definitions of `p` and `eq`

If you want to assign to other variables:

```
{v1, v2} = sol[[1, All, 2]];

{v1, v2}
```

[image]